# JavaScript prototyping basics

Tags: javascript

Can anyone, please explain in simple words why JavaScript expression

```
123.unexistingProperty;
```

throws an error, while

```
var v = 123;
v.unexistingProperty;
(123).unexistingProperty;
true.unexistingProperty;
"".unexistingProperty;
[].unexistingProperty;
{}.unexistingProperty;
```

do not?

Is this something to do with prototyping or just some rationale of the language?

P.S. Not just hypothetical, this comes up as a question when implementing `eval()` on dynamically generated code.

Comment: `v.unexistingFunction();` throws `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: i think 123 is `constant` while `v` is variable and v has some properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this something to do with prototyping

No, the reason is that Javascript doesn't allow you to access attributes directly on number literals.

For example this won't work:

```
123.unexistingProperty;
```

but this will work:

```
(123).unexistingProperty;
```

The thing is that a number can be written in the form of `10.5` Which means that the dot can't be use to access properties. For that reason, you'd have to wrap a number between parenthesis to call a property on the number.

Example:

```
Number.prototype.fun = function () { return "Fun" }
(100).fun()
(10.5).fun()
```

Comment: It feels like the last part of this answer is the only piece that makes sense: Use of dot ambiguity, following a number, which then would be just a language rationale.

Comment: @vitaly-t pretty much it